# Get tuples which pair up the values from two input lists

Tags: python

What is a Pythonic way to make combined tuple from a list?

e.g.
From:

```
a = [['A','B','C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

To:

```
[('A','D'), ('A', 'E'), ..., ('C', 'E'), ('C','F')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). If you have a list of lists, use the "splat" operator, `*`, to unpack them. `product` takes an arbitrary number of iterables:

```
>>> a = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]
>>> list(itertools.product(*a))

[('A', 'C', 'E'),
 ('A', 'C', 'F'),
 ('A', 'D', 'E'),
 ('A', 'D', 'F'),
 ('B', 'C', 'E'),
 ('B', 'C', 'F'),
 ('B', 'D', 'E'),
 ('B', 'D', 'F')]
```

Comment: You can unpack the list with `list(product(*a))`

Comment: Is there a generic way if I don't know the length of the list? e.g. a= [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]?

Comment: @alnet Yep, just use Akavall's hint. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Yes this is the right answer. But it has been asked and answered before, can you guys help close this question as dupe please?

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
[(x,y) for x in a[0] for y in a[1]]
```